# Product of a primitive matrix and its transpose.

Tags: matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Is it true that if $A$ is a nonnegative primitive matrix, then $AA^T$ is also primitive? Obviously $A^T$ is primitive but in general product of primitive matrices is not primitive. 
Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1&1&0\\ 0&1&1&0\\ 1&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&1},
\ A^2=\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1},
\ AA^T=\pmatrix{2&2&0&0\\ 2&2&0&0\\ 0&0&2&2\\ 0&0&2&2}.
$$

Comment: @daw I see. Thanks for catching that typo.