# If A is primitive, is AA' primitive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, nonnegative-matrices

Let $A$ be a primitive matrix (a square nonnegative matrix some power of which is positive). Is $AA^T$ necessarily primitive?

Comment: This was asked previously but unanswered:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2757515/product-of-a-primitive-matrix-and-its-transpose

Another related answered question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846195/if-a-is-irreducible-is-aa-irreducible

Comment: That question is now answered.

Comment: Thanks. It is very helpful.